# Neumann boundary conditions and interface conditions for electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, boundary-conditions, differential-equations

Let's suppose we have an isotropic homogeneous dielectric $D$ in the void, and a charge distribution $\rho(\vec{r})$. We want to find the potential $V(\vec{r})$ in the space. We have then to solve the Poisson equation with appropriate boundary conditions (in order to obtain an unique solution $V$).

We have to solve this equation separately in two distinct regions: in $D$ and in the volume $\tau=\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus D$ outside the dielectric. Obviously the boundary of $\tau$ is $\partial\tau=\partial D \cup S$, where $S$ is a surface at infinity, and where $\partial D$ is the surface of the dielectric (we supposbe by simplicity that on $\partial D$ there are no free charges).

The Poisson equation in the volume $\tau$ is $\nabla^2 V=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$, and we can use Dirichlet boundary conditions at infinity (imposing $V=0$ on $S$), and Neumann boundary conditions on $\partial D$.

Inside the dielectric $D$ the Poisson equation becomes $\nabla^2 V=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0\epsilon_r}$, and we can use Neumann boundary conditions on $\partial D$.

**My question**: is it correct to say that the Neumann boundary conditions on $\partial D$ are given in this case by the interface  condition $\vec{E}_1 \cdot \hat{n}=\epsilon_r\vec{E}_2 \cdot \hat{n}$, where $\hat{n}$ is the versor normal to $\partial D$? Here $\vec{E}_1$ and $\vec{E}_2$ represents the electric field inside and outside the dielectric, respectively.

Comment: what about the charge distribution? Is the charge only in $D$ or also   outside of $D$ ? Or is the charge respectively its density zero outside $D$. Actually if the non-zero charge is assumed up to infinity, then that might be a problem. Therefore it would useful to indicate to which volume the charge distribution is confined.

Comment: You are right. I am assuming that the charge is confined in a finite region $R$, and we can find free charges outside and/or inside the dielectric, but not on its surface.

Comment: Actually one will have both Dirichlet- and Neumann boundary conditions. At least at infinity one will assume that $V=0$ which is a Dirichlet-boundary condition. At the borders of the charge distribution one will also apply boundary conditions.  As  D and R are completely undetermined, the problem will have a certain degree of complexity which might require a numerical solution if there is no symmetry which simplifies significantly the problem.

Comment: I think it is sufficient to give, for example $V = 0$ at the far boundary and solve $\text{div}(\epsilon\vec{E})=\rho$ over the entire domain, and it is unnecessary to give the boundary conditions for the boundary of dielectric D and void.
If $\text{div}(\epsilon\vec{E})=\rho$ can be solved over the entire region, then I think the boundary conditions for dielectric D and void are automatically satisfied.
If the size of the far boundary is finite, then such a problem can be solved by the finite element method.